# Use .html pages with WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have wordpress in the same directory as my static .html pages. How can i make it so that when i want to visit example.com/test-page it will automatically go to the html version if there is a html version.

If there is no .html version, then it will go to the wordpress version. how can i do that? thanks

i have tried this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

but i think that only for index page. how can i do it globally? maybe thru .htaccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

This will internally redirect html requests eg : **/page/** to **/page.html**

Comment: It gives me a 404 page now. Should I add it before the default wordpress .htaccess code?

Comment: okay I added that before the default wordpress .htaccess code and it worked! thanks! :)